# Ajax returns undefined after json _encode() codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

Ajax returns undefined after json _encode() codeigniter
here is my code

**Model**

```
public function fetchclasses()
        {
           $query = $this->db->get('classes');
           return $query->result() ;
        }
```

**controller**

```
public function viewclass(){
        $result = $this->SM->fetchclasses();
        if(empty($result)){
            $response['error'] = True;
            $response['message'] = "no classes found";
        }
        else{
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = $result;
        }
         return json_encode($response);

    }
```

**jquery**

```
function getclass(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'home/viewclass',
            method : "GET",
            async: true,
            datatype : 'json',
            success : function(response){
                if(response.error == false){
                    console.log(response.message)
                }else{
                    console.log(response.message)
                }
            }
            
        })
        
    }
```

now if I do
console.log(response)

it outputs the answer

Comment: You've probably got unprintable characters prepended to the JSON, and it's probably  a BOM from an improperly-saved PHP file. 1. Check the response with a hex viewer, it probably begins with `\xEF\xBB\xBF`. 2. Check any recently edited files, see if they begin with `\xEF\xBB\xBF`. 3. Check your editor settings, always use "save UTF-8 without BOM".

Comment: You say "if I do console.log(response) it outputs the answer". What "answer" is it outputting?

Comment: It outputting all data from the database in JSON format

Comment: its ouputing   {"error":false,"message":[{"id":"1","classname":"jss1","classnumber":"1","classsection":"A"},{"id":"8","classname":"ss4","classnumber":"7","classsection":"A"}]}